# A problem in C/C++ programming

Tags: c++, c

I have to two loops with different conditions, but the code in loops is same.

Like this:

```
for (xx; xxxx; xxx)
{
    the Code
}

for (yy; yyyy; yyy)
{
    the Code
}
```

The problem is the code is too long and I want to write the code only one time and execute these two different loops.

How can I solve it?

Comment: ... use a function?  Please be more specific, otherwise this is a programming 101 question that we generally don't like here.

Comment: @Zack: Actually I don't mind "Programming 101" questions, as long as the OP put in some prior effort. (Then again, if they did put in some effort they probably wouldn't ask those types of questions in the first place.)

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you should put that long block of code in a function/method and invoke the function/method in the two loops?

```
type blockOfCode() {
    block of code...
    return type; //Or if it's is void nothing obviously.
}

for (xx, xxx, xxxx)
    blockOfCode();
for (yy, yyy, yyyy)
    blockOfCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it a function? That way you'll have one copy of the code and any changes / bug fixes you make would be reflected in both places.

An inline function would make it shorter but in terms of effects on the icache, its still going to be as long as your code.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put the code into a (n inline) function so it's shorter:

```
inline function a() { /* stuff */ }

for (x; xx; xxx) a();
for (y; yy; yyy) a();
```

Comment: `inline` doesn't guarantee the function is inlined. Plus, the OP said his code is long so I wouldn't recommend you inline it.

Comment: @Marlon yes, I know, it only suggests the compiler inline it. It's completely safe because if the compiler deems it will be more efficient to not inline it, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

you need to refactor the code to move the common code (in the for loops) into one function

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, and only if you are completely sure you can't use a function, then there is a nasty (emphasis on *nasty*!) fallback; the (justifiably) dreaded macro:

```
#define TheCode(p1) \
    do { \
        line1...; \
        line2...maybe using p1...; \
        line3...; \
    } while (0)

for (xx; xxxx; xxx)
{
    TheCode(x);
}

for (yy; yyyy; yyy)
{
    TheCode(y);
}
```

This is categorically not the recommended solution; using a function is superior.  But as an act of desparation, it might solve some problem.  On the whole, though, if you can't use a function, you've got problems with your existing code that you should solve before you fall back on this as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting `the Code` in a function that you'd call from inside each loop? Could that work for you?

Comment: @Rafer, there is no *better solution*. This is *the solution.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really hard to know exactly what you will need here, without a little more context as to what the conditions of your two `for` statements are, or some clue as to how any differences in your conditions appear within the loops. And, I definitely would much prefer to refactor it into another function rather than do something hacky to just make it work, since there are very likely many more issues with it than just being repeated if things are that complex.

But, if I *had* to do something like this, and I very much recommend against it if you have any way to avoid it, but you *can* do this (or some variation on it depending on your particular code and the nature of the `for` conditions):

### change this:

#### original code

```
// ... some code 

for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
}

// ... more code

for (int j=11; j < 20; ++j)
{
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
}

// ... rest of code
```

### to this:

#### modified code

```
// ... some code

for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    #include "badforloop.i"
}

// ... more code

for (int i=11; i < 20; ++i)
{
   #include "badforloop.i"
}

// ... rest of code
```

[NOTE: if, instead of the loop variable being `i` in both loops, it was different variables, you should modify them so they are the same.]

#### new file: badforloop.i

```
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
    // loop code  loop code  loop code
```

Comment: Gack! (But in case you do do this, it is more common to name the include file `.i` than `.h` when it's not exactly a header).

Comment: As regards 'Gack!': absolutely! but to be fair, this is really the only solution I see that meets the OPs needs. Turning it into a function is obviously the 'preferred' way to go, but apparently was tried and rejected by the OP. The other suggestion which would probably work is to turn the loop into a macro, which would require an awful lot of typing '\'s at line ends, in addition to making the incomprehensible loop also almost entirely undebuggable. (which, it doesn't sound like would be such a good idea given that the code is so complex it can't be moved into a function) :D

Comment: I think my gack was primarily triggered by the idea of defining the loop header as a macro instead of letting the include file contain only the body...

Comment: I think that was as important of a suggestion as changing from `.h` to `.i`, and have updated the code to reflect.